# using variable for ampscript Claimrow function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I plan to use many data extensions for voucher code
so I created a reference data extension and capture the data extension name from there

```
SET @getde = Lookup ("v1-reference", "DE", "date_code", @fullcode)
```

and then I claim the row

```
 SET @voucherrow = ClaimRow(@getde, "IsClaimed", "email", email)
```

but this will create an error
I've tried to put the data extension name directly in the function and it works:

```
SET @voucherrow = ClaimRow("voucher_pool", "IsClaimed", "email", email)
```

Is there any of you know how to achieve this, a workaround maybe. Thanks

here is the error:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the error? Also are you sure that @getde == "voucher_pool"?

Comment: I uploaded the error message. I am sure that @getde == "voucher_pool" I did test and retest

Answer (score 2):

I made it work this way:

```
    %%[
    SET @SubscriberKey = 'My_SubscriberKey'
    SET @de_name = 'My_DE_Name'
    TreatAsContent(Concat("%%[ SET @CouponRow = ClaimRow('", @de_name, "', 'IsClaimed', 'JobID', JobID, 'ListID', ListID, 'BatchID', _JobSubscriberBatchID, 'SubscriberKey', '", @SubscriberKey, "') ]%%"))

    IF NOT EMPTY(@CouponRow) THEN
    ]%%
    Your Coupon Code is %%=Field(@CouponRow,'CouponCode')=%%
    %%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

TreatAsContent will execute the code string and set the @CouponRow for later use.

I sometimes had an issue with the code erroring but I fixed it by closing and re-opening the AMPScript block tags around the TreatAsContent this way:

```
    ...
    ]%%
    %%[
    TreatAsContent(Concat("%%[ SET @CouponRow = ClaimRow('", @de_name, "', 'IsClaimed', 'JobID', JobID, 'ListID', ListID, 'BatchID', _JobSubscriberBatchID, 'SubscriberKey', '", @SubscriberKey, "') ]%%"))
    ]%%
    %%[
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ClaimRow()` and `ClaimRowValue()` functions do not accept variables for the Data Extension name, only literals.

Comment: Really horrible as to why it doesn't!  Little hang-ups like that with AMPScript continue to cause such useless delays.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to have email as the value in `ClaimRow(@getde, "IsClaimed", "email", email)`?  I would have expected a variable name like `@email`, or a personalization string like `emailaddr`.

Comment: No. I mean to have a variable for data extension name used by the claimrow function

Comment: OK, I was misunderstanding.  A grasping at straws kind of answer:  Have you tried declaring your variables using the VAR keyword at the beginning of your code?  99% of the time it doesn't matter, but I've a couple of issues where it does.

Comment: yes I did make sure that the var was there